# CSS Slide Multiple body background images

Tags: jquery, css

the below css code which moves the image from right to left but am unable to move multiple images have added a image also but that is not moving.

[jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/na0gwkrL/#&togetherjs=csP5tIR9Pf)

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://www.animaatjes.nl/disney-plaatjes/disney-plaatjes/finding-nemo/nemo11.gif"), url("http://www.marcofolio.net/images/stories/programming/webdesign/bgimg_slideshow/slideshow.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0%, 0;
    -moz-animation: swim 2s linear 0s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: swim 2s linear 0s infinite;
    animation: swim 2s linear 0s infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes swim {
    from { background-position: 200% 0, 0 0; }
    to  { background-position: -100% 0, 0 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes swim {
    from { background-position: 200% 0, 0 0; }
    to  { background-position: -100% 0, 0 0; }
}
@keyframes swim {
    from { background-position: 200% 0, 0 0; }
    to  { background-position: -100% 0, 0 0; }
}
```

Comment: Do you want slider to run continuously

Comment: @SiddharthPandey, yes with multiple images

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution. This is works for me....

You need to use jquery script.

```js
var currentBackground = 0;
var backgrounds = [];
backgrounds[0] = 'http://www.animaatjes.nl/disney-plaatjes/disney-plaatjes/finding-nemo/nemo11.gif';
backgrounds[1] = 'http://www.marcofolio.net/images/stories/programming/webdesign/bgimg_slideshow/slideshow.png';


function changeBackground() {
    currentBackground++;
    if(currentBackground == 2) currentBackground = 0;

    $('body').fadeOut(100,function() {
        $('body').css({
            'background-image' : "url('" + backgrounds[currentBackground] + "')"
        });
        $('body').fadeIn(100);
    });


    setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000);        
});







change your css to this :
```

```css
body {
  
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0%, 0;
    -moz-animation: swim 2s linear 0s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: swim 2s linear 0s infinite;
    animation: swim 2s linear 0s infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes swim {
    from { background-position: 200% 0, 0 0; }
    to  { background-position: -100% 0, 0 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes swim {
    from { background-position: 200% 0, 0 0; }
    to  { background-position: -100% 0, 0 0; }
}
@keyframes swim {
    from { background-position: 200% 0, 0 0; }
    to  { background-position: -100% 0, 0 0; }
}


Add jquery library if you have not added....
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You have done.....